# Position and scale background image according to a bounding box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a "profile picture" of an uploaded image by the user in a div:
[image: Result wanted]

I want this to work in every scenario, including ones where the face of the user is not centered in the original photo. So, for testing, I have produced 4 images where the face is positioned somewhere close to the corners of the image. I also want to use the original uploaded image and not process a cropped version of it, so I thought the simplest way would be to use background size & position properties

For now, I am able to set the background-size correctly, but the position is not working. I'm having a hard time figuring out what background-position i need to set so the face appears to be centered.

I believe my issue is that I don't fully understand how the background-size (in %) affects the background-position in CSS.

The best I can do is this:
https://jsfiddle.net/rg7eb9o6/7/

```
  let BoundingBox = {
    "Width": 0.20823267102241516,
    "Height": 0.4153777062892914,
    "Left": 0.16495604813098907,
    "Top": 0.19683583080768585
  };

  let imgWidth = 1000;
  let imgHeight = 726;
  let profilePicSize = 150;

  let bbw = BoundingBox.Width * imgWidth; //240
  let bbl = BoundingBox.Left * imgWidth;
  let bbh = BoundingBox.Height * imgHeight; //336
  let bbt = BoundingBox.Top * imgHeight;

  let bgSize = 100;
  if (bbw > bbh) {
    bgSize = imgWidth / bbw * 100;
  } else {
    bgSize = imgHeight / bbh * 100;
  }

  let bgPosX = BoundingBox.Left + (BoundingBox.Width / 2);
  let bgPosY = BoundingBox.Top + (BoundingBox.Height / 2);

  $(this).css({
    width: profilePicSize,
    height: profilePicSize,
    backgroundSize: bgSize + '%',
    backgroundPosition: (bgPosX * 100) + '% ' + (bgPosY * 100) + '%',
  });
```

[image: Result]

And as you can see, this is far from perfect. The 4 images should appear identical.

Comment: backgroundSize: 'cover', fits image to the box. else you need to change the BoundingBoxes property values.

Comment: @Mehrwarz yes but I don't need the image to cover the div, i need it to be larger, so the face fits perfectly

Comment: Well you can never fit the face perfectly without prerocessing the image to detect faces, or something like that. Anyone could upload an image with their face on the left and you wouldn't be able to see their face with your current code.

Comment: Probably best to let the user be responsible for providing an image that fits your bounding box.

Comment: @CasperKuethe Yes the face is detected using AWS Rekognition, hence the BoundingBox coordinated provided. And for what I need to do, I cannot rely on the user to provide an image that fits. I also cannot use a UI to allow the user to reposition the photo.